# Display queryset and it's foreign keys in order by id in django template

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates

I am building a quiz program. Every test has question and questions have options. Option has foreign key to a question and question has foreign key to a test. 
Every thing is good. But sometimes when displaying these in template, choice appear in reverse order that is sometimes choice d appears first and choice A appears last.

Here is the code:

```
{% for question in test.sscquestions_set.all %}

    <div class='well quest'>
         <h3 style= 'font-weight:bold;'> {{question.text}} </h3>   
               {% for choice in question.choices_set.all %}
                     <p> {{choice.text}}</p>
    </div>
{%endfor%}
```

How to always display choices in particular order (ie. OptionA first and Option D last)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or maybe you could specify the ordering in the model itself.

```
class Option(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['pk']
```

Answer (score 1):

Define a field for choices for example `choice_number` and then use

```
queryset|dictsort:'choice_number'
```

Comment: thanks ! but is it possible to do queryset|order_by:'id' ? because then i would not need to add choice_number field.

Comment: Yeah it is possible. Just try it out

Comment: i tried this: {% for j in i.choices_set.all|order_by:'pk' %}  but it shows an error:Invalid filter: 'order_by'

Comment: It's possible but hacky- it means whenever you're adding new choices you need to add them in the correct order every time. If you need to delete and add a new choice or similar, they'll be out of 'order'. Astik's solution is the correct one - don't be afraid of adding new fields to your models! :)

Comment: @Withnail, Thanks for that.

Comment: @PrashantPandey, I have updated my answer try with, `dictsort`. but still you need to add a field coz `pk` is not the choice ordering.

Comment: Rereading your comment Prashant, you'd been to define a template tag and import it to use order_by - like this - https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/741/ But honestly just add the field. :)

Comment: thanks for suggestions but the problem is i already have added 10000 questions and 4-5 options of each. Adding that field would not be feasible.